# Sortable containment for 'selected' or 'chosen' children inside a element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

jQuery sortable containment option takes a 'parent' or 'selector' for parent, and makes all the elements inside the parent contained or restricted inside the parent. 
My use case requires me to make certain elements who don't have a class 'x' can be dragged outside the parent and dropped elsewhere.

Here is my sortable options:

```
$('.sortable').sortable({
      cursor: 'auto',
      helper: 'clone',
      tolerance: 'pointer',
      connectWith: '.droppable',
      cursorAt: { top: 0, left: 0 },
      opacity: .9,
      scroll: false,
      revert: 180,
      containment:'parent'
    })
```

For example,

```
<div class="sortable">
  <div class="sortable">
   <div class="contain-parent"></div>
   <div class="contain-parent"></div>
   <div class="no-containment"></div>
 </div>
  <div class="contain-parent"></div>
  <div class="contain-parent"></div>
  <div class="no-containment"></div>
</div>
```

I want the children with class 'no-containment' to be able to sort outside of parent div.

Comment: can you share a jsfiddle or a pen of your code?